# How does nginx extract the ip from the url and then redirect to that ip?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

for example:

```
http://www.example.com/127.0.0.1/abc/1
```

redirect to

```
http://127.0.0.1/abc/1
```

ip `127.0.0.1` is dynamically variable

how do I write nginx configuration file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using RegEx, patterns can be grouped in parentheses and referenced with numbers

```
rewrite /([^/]+)(.*) http://$1$2 permanent;
```